# SVG Progressbar Animation with start circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

Is it possible to animate circle along with the line path ?

I have tried following code.can i merge the two line path and circle and apply transition for the same

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var svgPath = document.getElementById('heart');

    var path = new ProgressBar.Path(svgPath, {
        duration: 3000
    });
    path.animate(-1, {
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        duration: 2000
    }, function () {
        console.log('Animation has finished');
    });
});
```

```css
 #container {
 width:220px;
    position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:200px;height:200px;">

    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100.08 100" width="500"
        height="500">
        <path d="M50,2A48,48,0,1,1,2,50,48,48,0,0,1,50,2" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#eee" />
        <circle cx="95.87" cy="64.33" r="2.66" />
        <path id="heart" fill-opacity="0" d="M95.6,65.16A48,48,0,1,1,50,2" fill="none" stroke="#000" />
    </svg>


</div>
```

Comment: Not so sure what you mean by "animate the circle". Can you please clarify?

Comment: Check my example - Circle is not animated with path only stroke path was aniamted

Comment: So you want to circle itself to rotate (like a throbber)?

Comment: Not like throbber -I want circle animated with path and you can saw only path animated not circle

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not clear what exactly you are looking for. I'll one option as an answer, hope it will give you what you are looking for :)

Comment: you can saw svg code -> circle and path tag was not merge i want transition both (circle and path)

Comment: I don't want spin effect, I want that black circle to be move on the bigger gray circle from 0 to 170 degree.

Comment: Got what you are looking for. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library allows you to pass a `step` function that is called for every step in the animation.

Using that, the value returned by the `value()` function, and a couple of handy SVG path functions, you can calculate the coordinates of the end of the progress line.  You can then use those coordinates to position the circle.

Demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var svgPath = document.getElementById('heart'); 
  
  var shape = new ProgressBar.Path(svgPath);
  var pathLen = shape.path.getTotalLength();

  shape.animate(-1, {
 easing: 'easeOutBounce',
    duration: 2000,
    attachment: document.getElementById("circle"),
    step: function(state, shape, attachment) {
      // 'attachment' is a DOM reference to the circle element
      var val =  1 + shape.value();  // buggy value() function?
      var endPosition = shape.path.getPointAtLength(val * pathLen);
      attachment.cx.baseVal.value = endPosition.x;
      attachment.cy.baseVal.value = endPosition.y;
    }
  }, function() {
    console.log('Animation has finished');
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  width:220px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
 <div id="container" style="width:200px;height:200px;">

    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100.08 100" width="500" height="500">
    <path d="M50,2A48,48,0,1,1,2,50,48,48,0,0,1,50,2" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#eee"/>
    <circle id="circle" cx="95.87" cy="64.33" r="2.66"/>
    <path  id="heart" fill-opacity="0"  d="M95.6,65.16A48,48,0,1,1,50,2" fill="none" stroke="#000" />
    </svg>


    </div>
```

Note that the library seems to have a bug.  According to the docs, the `value()` function is supposed to return a value between `0` and `1`. However it returns a value between `0` and `-1`. Plus it's back-to-front.  So to get the right progress value, I had to add `1` to the value of `shape()`.  If you ever update to a new version of the library that fixes this bug, you may have to alter this code.