# SVG Animated Graph Arrow

Tags: svg, svg-animate, inline-svg

This is my first time using SVG and I want to know if it is possible to create an animated line graph with an arrow. I have found multiple examples of animated line graphs without arrows, non-animated line graphs with arrows, and animated straight lines with arrows, but not exactly what I am looking for. I have attached some codepen examples I've been playing around with below. Does anyone know if this is possible/have a solution? It would be greatly appreciated!

1. Animated line missing arrow (needs arrow):
   http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/jVaObd

   ```
   # HTML
   <div class="graph__wrapper">
     <svg width="315px" height="107px" viewBox="0 0 315 107" version="1.1">
       <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
         <path d="M2.10546875,95.75 L40.5546875,68.3476562 L55.2109375,81.1796875 L65.2148437,76.3945312 L96.1835937,86.8320312 L131.023438,19.9414062 L142.15625,23.7226562 L183.605469,2.1953125 L211.007812,22.3320312 L234.320312,71.5664062 L234.667969,83.0039062 L244.019531,83.0039062 L247.105469,88.8320312 L312.695312,104.839844" id="Path-1" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" class="path"></path>
       </g>
     </svg>
   </div> 


   # CSS(Less)

   @import "lesshat";

   @darkgrey:          #303030;

   *{
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   body{
     background: @darkgrey;
   }

   .graph__wrapper{
     width: 400px;
     margin: 30px auto;
     position: relative;

     svg{
       position: absolute;
       margin: 36px 0px 0px 15px;
     }
   }

   .path {
     stroke-dasharray: 1000;
     stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
     animation: dash 3s ease-in forwards;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-delay: 1s;
   }

   @keyframes dash {
     to {
       stroke-dashoffset: 0;
     }
   }

   .description{
     font-family: "Roboto";
     color:lighten(@darkgrey, 50%);
     text-align: center;
     margin: 40px 0px;
   }
   ```
2. Animated straight line with arrow (needs to stop at multiple points on path):
   http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/yVPYrY
3. I tried adding the path descriptions from #1 to #2 and it has the desired final graph, just no animations:
   http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/pNdgWR
4. I also tried adding the arrow marker from #2 to #1, but the arrow doesn't animate: 
   http://codepen.io/alexandraleigh/pen/aBVdVY

I'm also open to using a plugin such as http://snapsvg.io/, but haven't seen any working examples that help my situation.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864442/svg-progressbar-animation-with-start-circle/40865930 more-or-less. Except you want to use a triangle instead of a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with offset-motion(old syntax: motion-path).
Be aware that this is a heighly experimental feature. it currently only works in Chrome. More to the point i use the "old" syntax here as that is what currently works in chrome, but it will soon switch to the new systax...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #303030;
}
.graph__wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 36px 0px 0px 15px;
  }
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 428;
  stroke-dashoffset: 428;
  animation: dash 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes pm {
  from {
    motion-offset: 0%;
  }
  to {
    motion-offset: 100%
  }
}
#arrow {
  animation: pm 3s ease-in forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  motion-path: path('M2.10546875,95.75 L40.5546875,68.3476562 L55.2109375,81.1796875 L65.2148437,76.3945312 L96.1835937,86.8320312 L131.023438,19.9414062 L142.15625,23.7226562 L183.605469,2.1953125 L211.007812,22.3320312 L234.320312,71.5664062 L234.667969,83.0039062 L244.019531,83.0039062 L247.105469,88.8320312 L312.695312,104.839844');
  motion-rotation: auto;
  motion-anchor: center;
}
.description {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: lighten(@darkgrey, 50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph__wrapper">
  <svg width="315px" height="107px" viewBox="0 0 315 107" version="1.1" style="overflow:visible">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
      <path d="M2.10546875,95.75 L40.5546875,68.3476562 L55.2109375,81.1796875 L65.2148437,76.3945312 L96.1835937,86.8320312 L131.023438,19.9414062 L142.15625,23.7226562 L183.605469,2.1953125 L211.007812,22.3320312 L234.320312,71.5664062 L234.667969,83.0039062 L244.019531,83.0039062 L247.105469,88.8320312 L312.695312,104.839844"
      id="Path-1" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" class="path"></path>



      <polyline id="arrow" points="0,-5 10,0 0,5 1,0" fill="white" />

    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

you can also do this with `animateMotion`, but svg animations are soon to be depricted. You will have to rewrite your code in any way sooner or later :-(

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #303030;
}
.graph__wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 36px 0px 0px 15px;
  }
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 428;
  stroke-dashoffset: 428;
  animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.description {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: lighten(@darkgrey, 50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph__wrapper">
  <svg width="315px" height="107px" viewBox="0 0 315 107" version="1.1" style="overflow:visible">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
      <path d="M2.10546875,95.75 L40.5546875,68.3476562 L55.2109375,81.1796875 L65.2148437,76.3945312 L96.1835937,86.8320312 L131.023438,19.9414062 L142.15625,23.7226562 L183.605469,2.1953125 L211.007812,22.3320312 L234.320312,71.5664062 L234.667969,83.0039062 L244.019531,83.0039062 L247.105469,88.8320312 L312.695312,104.839844"
      id="Path-1" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" class="path"></path>



      <polyline id="arrow" points="0,-5 10,0 0,5 1,0" fill="white">
        <animateMotion rotate="auto" begin="1s" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze">
          <mpath xlink:href="#Path-1" />
        </animateMotion>
      </polyline>

    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```